# jquery validator plugin ignore title attribute to show error message

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

How can I ignore title attribute to show error message in jquery validator plugin. Because i am using that title to show tooltip not for error message.

plugin initialization

```
$('#participantform').validate();
```

form element to validate

```
<input name="o_phone_cnt" class="inputtextie required digits" title="Country Code" style="width:25px" type="text" minlength="1" size="3" maxlength="3"/>
```

on button click

```
$('#sendmail_ppnt').button().click(function(){
      $('#participantform').submit();
});
```

at the validation time it showing error message as ***required***, but after adding the title to the input:text element it is showing ***Country Code*** as error message.

how to configure validator plugin to ignore title attribute to show error message.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can pass the [ignoreTitle](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions) option to `validate()`:

```
$("#participantform").validate({
    ignoreTitle: true
});
```

In passing, note that the documentation says (emphasis mine):

> Set to skip reading messages from the title attribute, helps to avoid
>   issues with Google Toolbar; default is false for compatibility, *the
>   message-from-title is likely to be completely removed in a future
>   release*.

So, chances are you won't have to anything to obtain the behavior that you want with future releases of the plugin.